# Why Stripe's webhooks do not need verify signature?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Neither doc (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) nor SDK(stripe-php) uses any signature method. So I doubt, what if someone fake as official webhook sender?

In SDK, only retrieve event id successfully will consider a good webhook, I think it's too risky, isn't it?

Comment: It seems like stripe heard you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. They have been covered already but I will consolidate everything into a single answer.

**Option 1**

Check the event is valid (throws an exception if not).

```
\Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_id)
```

**Option 2**

HMAC the `Stripe-Signature` header using the `whsec*` key found in your dashboard.

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

// You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
$endpoint_secret = "whsec_...";

$payload = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$sig_header = $_SERVER["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"];
$event = null;

try {
  $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
  );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
  // Invalid payload
  http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
  exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Error\SignatureVerification $e) {
  // Invalid signature
  http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
  exit();
}

// Do something with $event

http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
```

Code from https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures

Option 1 is simpler, requires an extra call to the API but option 2 requires you store an extra key in your application and requires for code (I prefer option 1). I checked with Stripe support today and they confirmed they are both as good as each other in terms of verifying the validity of an API call so it is a matter of choice.

Comment: Option 1 is great and I did not found a similar solution elsewhere

Comment: I met [an issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/issues/1223) with option 2, but option 1 worked well and think it a good way as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Stripe does provide signatures for web hooks. Take a look here: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#signatures

You can also take a look at this article: https://www.truespotmedia.com/testing-webhooks-in-stripe-with-php/

Here is some example code:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("your secret api key");

// You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
$endpoint_secret = "whsec_...";

$payload = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$sig_header = $_SERVER["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"];
$event = null;

try {
  $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
  );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
  // Invalid payload
  http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
  exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Error\SignatureVerification $e) {
  // Invalid signature
  http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
  exit();
}

// Do something with $event

http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by saving the event id and then retrieving the event from stripe to make sure the event is valid:

```
\Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_id)
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I saw the code in SDK, but I don't understand why stripe consider a retrieve on event_id successfully is a legal webhook, why? What if some one fake a data just use the same retrievable event and same event id?

Comment: Phoenix, you are retrieving the event from Stripe directly, so for that to happen a faker would have had to come up with the same event id generated by Stripe to make this possible.

Comment: you know, it sucks. for each event, we need to make extra call to stripe's server. i wonder why they do not have signature mechanism like all the other companies.